# Cannot crop my favicon in Localhost (Xampp) Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, xampp

[image: Here's the problem]

Hi. Recently I'm doing a Wordpress Project on localhost Xampp server. Despite I am having problems in cropping the favicon. Is there any PHP code I have to change. I have also turned off the UAC but the problems remain same.

Comment: Hi there. Please also try to include the relevant error logs from XAMPP that could tell more about why the cropping failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
You try smaller icon size like 250x250
```

refer this link for more - https://wordpress.org/support/article/creating-a-favicon/